# Как создать неровные закругленные стороны на DIV?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, background

Я пытаюсь сделать DIV с разными по форме закругленными сторонами, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я проверил некоторые решения, и самое близкое к желаемому результату, которое я смог получить, это - `border-radius`. Я использовал:

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 80%50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 30%30px;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться разной формы закругленных концов, как на первой картинке в вопросе?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50439518/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать только `border-radius`, то сделать острый угол у границы не получится, но всё равно можно добиться гораздо более близкого результата, если задавать отдельно задавать значения скругления по каждой из осей:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 60px;
  width: 325px;
  height: 250px;

  border: 1px dotted red;
  border-radius: 0 0 150px 190px / 0 0 50px 150px;
}

img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKBC.png>
<div></div>
```

Если есть возможность обернуть элемент ы другой и подрезать при помощи `overflow: hidden на внешнем`, то всё ещё лучше. Вот сначала просто блоки нужной формы (можно подогнать ещё лучше, но мне лень):

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 60px;
  width: 325px;
  height: 250px;
}

.c {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

.r {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 50px;
}

.l {
  width: 375px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 256px 183px;
}

img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKBC.png>
<div class=c></div>
<div class=r></div>
<div class=l></div>
```

А теперь вкладываем (и увеличиваем размер на 2px, которые раньше добавлялись из-за border):

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.c {
  top: 32px;
  left: 60px;
  width: 327px;
  height: 252px;
}

.r {
  right: -25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 50px;
}

.l {
  left: -50px;
  right: 25px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 256px 183px;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, silver, white, silver);
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/veKBC.png>

<div class=c>
  <div class=r>
    <div class=l>
      <main>html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video</main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

- Вы можете рассмотреть использование  [clip-path:](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(75% at 65% 10%);
  clip-path: circle(75% at 65% 10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

- Или использовать [radial-gradient:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 10%, blue 75%,transparent 75.5%);

}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

- Или используйте псевдоэлемент и добавьте `overflow`:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box:before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:-10%;
 right:-10%;
 bottom:10%;
 background:blue;
 border-radius:0 0 50% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

- И давайте не будем забывать решение SVG (как обычный элемент или фон)

```css
svg {
 display:inline-block;
}

.box {
  display:inline-block;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 64 64'  width='200' height='200' fill='blue'> <path d='M0 0 L0 28 C10 46 30 60 64 48 L64 0 Z' /></svg>")0 0/100% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<svg
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  viewBox='0 0 64 64'
  width='200' height='200'
  fill='blue'>
  <path d='M0 0 L0 28 C10 46 30 60 64 48 L64 0 Z' />
</svg>

<div class="box">
</div>
```

Вот хороший [онлайн-инструмент](http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0%200%20L0%2028%20C10%2046%2030%2060%2064%2048%20L64%200%20Z) для легкого получения SVG

Comment: Блин.. Это был круг?? Перемудрил я с ответом :(

Comment: @ Qwertiy Да, это был круг, кроме варианта SVG.

Comment: Я тогда мог бы одним вложенным div'ом с `border-radius: 50%` обойтись)) Ну вот почему я сначала пишу ответ, а потом читаю? ((

Comment: @Qwertiy Всё нормально получилось. :=) Так добавь просто ещё один вариант. Пусть всё в одном топике будет собрано