# Как создать многострочный tooltip в SVG

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, html5, svg

В SVG тултип реализуется с помощью парного тега **`<title>` Текст подсказки `</title>`**

Чтобы тултип начал показываться при наведении курсора на объект, необходимо объект обернуть групповыми тегами `<g>`:

```
<g>
    <title>Первый атом</title>   
     <circle cy="-44" r="9"/>
</g> 
   <g>
     <title>Второй атом</title>
     <circle cx="40" cy="18" r="9"/>
   </g>
      <g>
         <title>Третий атом</title> 
         <circle cx="-40" cy="18" r="9"/>
     </g>
```

Ниже пример однострочных тултипов для объектов SVG.
Наведите курсор на атомы, траектории движения атомов и и через некоторое время должна появиться всплывающая подсказка.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-52 -53 100 100" stroke-width="2">
 <g fill="none">
   <g> 
     <title> Орбита первого атома  </title> 
    <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#66899a" rx="6" ry="44" />
   </g>  
       <g>     
        <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#e1d85d" rx="6" ry="44"  transform="rotate(-66)"/>
    <title> Орбита второго атома  </title> 
  </g>  
  <g> 
      <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#80a3cf" rx="6" ry="44" transform="rotate(66)"/>
       <title> Орбита третьего атома  </title> 
  </g>   
  <circle  stroke="#4b541f" r="44"/> 
 </g> 
 <g fill="#66899a" stroke="white">
   <g>   
     <title> Ядро </title>
     <circle fill="#80a3cf" r="13"/>
   </g>
     <g>
      <title>Первый атом</title>   
      <circle cy="-44" r="9"/>
     </g> 
   <g>
    <title>Третий атом</title> 
     <circle cx="-40" cy="18" r="9"/>
  </g> 
   <g>
    <title>Второй атом</title>
     <circle cx="40" cy="18" r="9"/>
   </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

К сожалению, тултипы не подлежат стилизации, то есть невозможно изменить цвет, размер шрифта и другие текстовые атрибуты.

Теги переноса текста на другую строку `<tspan> ... </tspan>` тоже не работают.

**Вопрос:**

Есть ли способ создать многострочный тултип **только средствами SVG**,
то есть перенос строки в любом месте текста?

Comment: Что за муть в тегах? И зачем атом вообще нужен?

Comment: @Qwertiy вместо атома может быть любой набор базовых SVG элементов. Картинка атома чисто для примера

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо просто поставить в коде перевод строки:

```css
html, body, svg {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vmin;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-4 -4 8 8">
  <g>
    <title>Многострочный
тултип - это
очень легко!</title>
    <circle r=4 fill=silver />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: вот здесь ещё можно ответить [Как создать неровные закругленные стороны на DIV?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/982176/28748)

Answer (score 6):

И всё-таки, как оказалось,  есть способ сделать многострочный тултип только встроенными средствами SVG.

### Пример многострочного тултипа

Многострочный тултип реализуется с помощью вложенных друг в друга парных тегов `<title>`.

Структура вложения следующая:

```
<g>   
     <title> 
       <title> &#10697; Свойства атома </title>
        <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
         <title> Название: кислород </title>
          <title> Атомная масса (молярная масса) :15,99903 </title>
           <title> Радиус атома    60 (48) пм  </title> 
            <title> &#10697; Химические свойства  </title>
           <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
          <title> Ковалентный радиус    73 пм </title>
         <title> Радиус иона    132 (-2e) пм </title>
        <title> Электродный потенциал    0 </title>
       <title>&#10697;Термодинамические свойства простого вещества </title>
      <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
       <title>Плотность (при н. у.)    газ: 1,42897 кг/м³ </title>
        <title>Температура плавления    54,8 К (-218,35 °C) </title>
         <title>Температура кипения    90,19 К (-182,96 °C) </title>

     </title>
     <circle fill="#80a3cf" r="13"/>

    </g>
```

Внутрь первой пары `<title>`, которая идёт без текста,  последовательно вкладываются парные теги `<title> с текстом ….. </title>`.

Каждая пара отвечает за свою отдельную строку многострочного тултипа.

Допускается добавлять символы *Unicode*.

В примере ниже я добавил в заголовки символ сдвоенного прямоугольника – ⧉ и несколько символов *Unicode* отображающие черту, для визуального разделения заголовков и остального текста ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

Наведите курсор на центральный круг и появится многострочная подсказка. На остальных элементах остались одно строчные тултипы.

```css
.container {
width:40%;
height:40%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-52 -53 100 100" stroke-width="2">
 
 <g fill="none">
   <g> 
     <title> Орбита первого атома  </title> 
    <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#66899a" rx="6" ry="44" />
   </g>  
       <g>     
        <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#e1d85d" rx="6" ry="44"  transform="rotate(-66)"/>
    <title> Орбита второго атома  </title> 
  </g>  
  <g> 
      <ellipse fill="#F0F0F0" stroke="#80a3cf" rx="6" ry="44" transform="rotate(66)"/>
       <title> Орбита третьего атома  </title> 
  </g>   
  
    
   <circle  stroke="#4b541f" r="44"/> 
   

 </g> 
 <g fill="#66899a" stroke="white">
   <g>   
     <title> 
    <title>   &#10697;   Свойства атома </title>
    <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
    <title> Название: кислород </title>
    <title> Атомная масса (молярная масса) :15,99903 </title>
    <title> Радиус атома 60 (48) пм  </title> 
    <title> &#10697; Химические свойства  </title>
     <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
    <title> Ковалентный радиус 73 пм </title>
    <title> Радиус иона 132 (-2e) пм </title>
    <title> Электродный потенциал 0 </title>
    <title>&#10697;Термодинамические свойства простого вещества </title>
     <title> &#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135;&#9135; </title>
    <title>Плотность (при н. у.) газ: 1,42897 кг/м³ </title>
    <title>Температура плавления 54,8 К (-218,35 °C) </title>
    <title>Температура кипения 90,19 К (-182,96 °C) </title>
    
  </title>
     <circle fill="#80a3cf" r="13"/>
      
    </g>
  
 <g>
    <title>Первый атом</title>   
     <circle cy="-44" r="9"/>
 </g> 
   <g>
     <title>Второй атом</title>
     <circle cx="40" cy="18" r="9"/>
   </g>
      <g>
         <title>Третий атом</title> 
         <circle cx="-40" cy="18" r="9"/>
     </g> 
   
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```