# На чем можно сделать свою карту для сайта?

Tags: javascript, svg, openlayers

Нужно сделать интерактивную карту для сайта, проблема в том что карта не существующая.
Как и на чем можно сделать полностью свою карту, с векторными кастомизируемыми по условиям тайлами, возможностью размещать метки, вызывать попапы по кликам на зоны карты.

Я знаю про openlayers, но этот mapbox завязан на сторонних сервисах координат и тайлах, я не смог найти инфу можно ли сделать полностью свою карту со своими координатами.

Если знаете как правильно делать такие карты, или как сделать для openlayers свои векторные тайлы и координаты для этого дела дайте наводку)

Уточнение: нужна возможность добавлять метки из админки сайта, они не должны быть вшиты в саму карту.

Answer (score 3):

> Как и на чем можно сделать полностью свою карту, с векторными
> кастомизируемыми по условиям тайлами, возможностью размещать метки,
> вызывать попапы по кликам на зоны карты.

Сделать можно всё это на **SVG**
Для вывода подсказок по наведению на определенный участок карты можно применить тег SVG `<title>...</title>`

Если вы хотите реализовать вывод подсказки, например, какого-то участка карты,
то необходимо обернуть `path`, который рисует этот участок групповым тегом `<g>`.

И разместить внутри него двойной тег `<title>` с поясняющим текстом.

Пример:

```
<g>
<title>   "UT" - Utah
      State capital city - Salt Lake City
      Population
      City  186,440
      Estimate Estimate (2018)  200,591
 </title> 
      <path d="M0 0...."/>
</g>
```

```html
<style>
.state {
fill:white;
stroke:dodgerblue;
transition:  1s;
}
:hover.state {
 fill:blue;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:4px;
 }
</style>
<body>
   <section id="map">

    <svg version="1.1"
       id="svg2" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="467 -284 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
      <g>
      <title>"ID" - IDAHO
State capital city - Boise
Population - 228,790
      </title>
      <path id="ID"  class="state" d="
        M615.5-107.5l8.8-35.2l1.4-4.2l2.5-5.9l-1.3-2.3l-2.5,0.1l-0.8-1l0.5-1.1l0.3-3.1l4.5-5.5l1.8-0.5l1.1-1.1l0.6-3.2l0.9-0.7l3.9-5.8
        l3.9-4.3l0.2-3.8l-3.4-2.6l-1.5-4.4l13.6-63.3l13.5,2.5l-4.4,21.4l3.6,7.5l-1.6,4.7l2,4.6l3.1,1.3l3.8,9.6l3.5,4.4l0.5,1.1l3.3,1.1
        l0.4,2.1l-7,17.4l-0.2,2.6l2.6,3.3l0.9,0l4.9-3l0.7-1.1l1.6,0.7l-0.3,5.4l2.7,12.6l3.9,3.2l1.7,2.2l-0.7,4.1l1.1,2.8l1.1,1.1
        l2.5-2.4l2.8,0l2.9,1.3l2.8-0.7l3.8-0.2l4,1.6l2.7-0.3l0.5-3l2.9-0.8l1.3,1.5l0.4,2.9l1.4,1.2l-8.4,53.6
        C710.4-89.3,622.5-106,615.5-107.5z"/> 
        </g>
  <g>    
    <title>"UT" - Utah
State capital city - Salt Lake City
Population
City    186,440
Estimate Estimate (2018)    200,591
      </title>
      <path id="UT"  class="state" d="M726.5,26.1l-83.7-11.9
        l20.6-112.5l46.8,8.7l-1.5,10.6l-2.3,13.2l7.8,0.9l16.4,1.8l8.2,0.9L726.5,26.1z"/>
</g>
      <g>    
    <title>"AZ" - Arizona
State capital city - Phoenix
Population
City    1,445,632
Estimate Estimate (2018)    1,660,272
      </title>
      <path id="AZ" class="state" d="
        M611.9,98.6l-2.6,2.2l-0.3,1.5l0.5,1l18.9,10.7l12.1,7.6l14.7,8.6l16.8,10l12.3,2.4l25,2.7l17.3-119.1l-83.7-11.9l-3.1,16.4l-1.6,0
        l-1.7,2.6l-2.5-0.1l-1.3-2.7l-2.7-0.3l-0.9-1.1H628l-0.9,0.6l-1.9,1l-0.1,7l-0.2,1.7l-0.6,12.6l-1.5,2.2l-0.6,3.3l2.7,4.9l1.3,5.8
        l0.8,1l1,0.6l-0.1,2.3l-1.6,1.4l-3.4,1.7l-1.9,1.9l-1.5,3.7l-0.6,4.9l-2.9,2.7l-2.1,0.7l0.1,0.8l-0.5,1.7l0.5,0.8l3.7,0.6l-0.6,2.7
        l-1.5,2.2L611.9,98.6z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>"NV" - Nevada
State capital city - Carson City
Population
City    55,274
Estimate Estimate (2018)    55,414
      </title>
      <path id="NV" class="state" d="M663.4-98.4
        L639.8,30.4l-1.8,0.3l-1.6,2.4l-2.4,0l-1.5-2.7l-2.6-0.4l-0.8-1.1l-1-0.1l-2.8,1.6l-0.3,6.8l-0.4,5.8l-0.3,8.6l-1.4,2.1l-2.4-1.1
        L551.3-51.5l19-67.6L663.4-98.4z"/>
</g>        
<g>    
    <title>"OR" - Oregon
State capital city - Salem
Population
City    154,637
Estimate Estimate (2018)    173,442
      </title>
      <path id="OR" class="state" d="
        M615.7-108.5l8.9-34.8l1.1-4.2l2.4-5.6l-0.6-1.2l-2.5,0l-1.3-1.7l0.5-1.5l0.5-3.2l4.5-5.5l1.8-1.1l1.1-1.1l1.5-3.6l4-5.7l3.6-3.9
        l0.2-3.5l-3.3-2.5l-1.8-4.6l-12.7-3.6l-15.1-3.5l-15.4,0.1l-0.5-1.4l-5.5,2.1l-4.5-0.6l-2.4-1.6l-1.3,0.7l-4.7-0.2l-1.7-1.4
        l-5.3-2.1l-0.8,0.1l-4.3-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.2-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.7-0.8l0.2-7.8l-2.3-3.9l-4.1-0.6l-0.7-2.5l-2.4-0.5l-5.8,2.1l-2.3,6.5
        l-3.2,10l-3.2,6.5l-5,14.1l-6.5,13.6l-8.1,12.6l-1.9,2.9l-0.8,8.6l0.4,12.1L615.7-108.5z"/>
</g>     
     <g>
      <title>"WA" - Washington Territory
State capital city - Olympia
Population
City    46,478
Estimate (2018) 52,555
      </title>
      <path id="WA" class="state" class="state" d="
        M569.1-276.4l4.4,1.5l9.7,2.7l8.6,1.9l20,5.7l23,5.7l15.2,3.2l-13.6,63.6l-12.4-3.5l-15.5-3.6l-15.2,0l-0.5-1.3l-5.6,2.2l-4.6-0.7
        l-2.1-1.6L579-200l-4.7-0.1l-1.7-1.3l-5.3-2.1l-0.7,0.1l-4.4-1.5l-1.9,1.8l-6.3-0.3l-5.9-4.1l0.8-0.9l0.1-7.7l-2.3-3.8l-4.1-0.6
        l-0.7-2.5l-2.3-0.5l-3.6,1.2l-2.3-3.2l0.3-2.9l2.7-0.3l1.6-4l-2.6-1.1l0.2-3.7l4.4-0.6l-2.7-2.7l-1.5-7.1l0.6-2.9v-7.9l-1.8-3.2
        l2.3-9.4l2.1,0.5l2.4,2.9l2.7,2.6l3.2,1.9l4.5,2.1l3.1,0.6l2.9,1.5l3.4,1l2.3-0.2v-2.4l1.3-1.1l2.1-1.3l0.3,1.1l0.3,1.8l-2.3,0.5
        l-0.3,2.1l1.8,1.5l1.1,2.4l0.6,1.9l1.5-0.2l0.2-1.3l-1-1.3l-0.5-3.2l0.8-1.8l-0.6-1.5v-2.3l1.8-3.6l-1.1-2.6l-2.4-4.9l0.3-0.8
        L569.1-276.4z M559.6-270.4l2-0.2l0.5,1.4l1.5-1.6h2.3l0.8,1.5l-1.5,1.7l0.6,0.8l-0.7,2l-1.4,0.4c0,0-0.9,0.1-0.9-0.2
        s1.5-2.6,1.5-2.6l-1.7-0.6l-0.3,1.5l-0.7,0.6l-1.5-2.3L559.6-270.4z"/>
  </g> 
  <g>
      <title>"CA" - California
State capital city - Sacramento
Population
City    466,488
Estimate (2018) 508,529
      </title>
      <path id="CA" class="state" d="
        M611.7,98.2l3.9-0.5l1.5-2l0.5-2.9l-3.6-0.6l-0.5-0.7l0.5-2l-0.2-0.6l1.9-0.6l3-2.8l0.6-5l1.4-3.4l1.9-2.2l3.5-1.6l1.7-1.6l0.1-2.1
        l-1-0.6l-1-1.1l-1.2-5.8l-2.7-4.8l0.6-3.5l-2.4-1L551.3-51.5l18.9-67.6l-67.1-15.7l-1.5,4.7l-0.2,7.4l-5.2,11.8l-3.1,2.6l-0.3,1.1
        l-1.8,0.8l-1.5,4.2l-0.8,3.2l2.7,4.2l1.6,4.2l1.1,3.6l-0.3,6.5l-1.8,3.1l-0.6,5.8l-1,3.7l1.8,3.9l2.7,4.5l2.3,4.9l1.3,4l-0.3,3.2
        l-0.3,0.5v2.1l5.7,6.3l-0.5,2.4l-0.6,2.3l-0.6,1.9l0.2,8.2l2.1,3.7l1.9,2.6l2.7,0.5l1,2.7l-1.1,3.6l-2.1,1.6h-1.1l-0.8,3.9l0.5,2.9
        l3.2,4.4l1.6,5.3l1.5,4.7l1.3,3.1l3.4,5.8l1.5,2.6l0.5,2.9l1.6,1v2.4l-0.8,1.9l-1.8,7.1l-0.5,1.9l2.4,2.7l4.2,0.5l4.5,1.8l3.9,2.1
        h2.9l2.9,3.1l2.6,4.9l1.1,2.3l3.9,2.1l4.8,0.8l1.5,2.1l0.6,3.2l-1.5,0.6l0.3,1l3.2,0.8l2.7,0.2l3.2-1.7l3.9,4.2l0.8,2.3l2.6,4.2
        l0.3,3.2v9.4l0.5,1.8l10,1.5l19.7,2.7L611.7,98.2z M523.6,54.5l1.3,1.5l-0.2,1.3l-3.2-0.1l-0.6-1.2l-0.6-1.5L523.6,54.5z
         M525.5,54.5l1.2-0.6l3.6,2.1l3.1,1.2l-0.9,0.6l-4.5-0.2l-1.6-1.6L525.5,54.5z M546.2,74.3l1.8,2.3l0.8,1l1.5,0.6l0.6-1.5l-1-1.8
        l-2.7-2l-1.1,0.2V74.3z M544.7,82.9l1.8,3.2l1.2,1.9l-1.5,0.2l-1.3-1.2c0,0-0.7-1.5-0.7-1.9s0-2.2,0-2.2L544.7,82.9z"/>
        </g>
    </svg>

  </section>
</body>
```

### Note:

*Если у вас не будет работать всплывающая подсказка, обязательно проверьте отсутствие стиля `pointer-events:none;` так как при этом происходит отключение событий мыши.*

Связанные вопросы:

1. [Как создать многострочный tooltip в SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/982226/28748)
2. [Как при наведении курсора на один из элементов SVG добиться, чтобы он
   поднялся выше других элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1015588/28748)